# Screen flickering on second monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, monitor, flicker

I am experiencing really bad screen flickering on my second monitor in Ubuntu. 
I'm not sure how to go about fixing this, it's plugged in via DVI. 
If I don't do anything the screen rarely flickers (it does but it's very little and in a rhythmic pattern), but if I type or move my mouse around it flickers like crazy. 
Here's the output of `sudo lshw -C video`:

```
     *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: C79 [GeForce 9400M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: b1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:25 memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff     memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:1000(size=128) memory:d3000000-d301ffff
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you installed the Nvidia driver for your GPU?